# How to Determine the Size of a TimescaleDB Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

To determine the size of my TimescaleDB table `my_table` (which has a hypertable created previously), I ran the SQL query

```
pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('my_table') );
```

However, despite having 10k rows in this table, the size returned from this query is *24 kB*.

Querying for the size of the database gave a more reasonable size of *34 MB*, using the SQL query

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('database_development') );
```

**Question:** What is the correct way for calculating the size of a TimescaleDB table?

*Using PostgreSQL 11.5, TimescaleDB 1.5.1*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We typically recommend using TimescaleDB-specific functions:

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#hypertable_relation_size
   https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#hypertable_relation_size_pretty

If you are interested in getting information about each/specific chunk:

https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#chunk_relation_size
   https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#chunk_relation_size_pretty

Comment: links are out of date

Comment: with 2.0 its:  SELECT hypertable_size()

Comment: To have a value in human readable form: `SELECT pg_size_pretty( hypertable_size('<schema>.<table>'))`;